# Is it possible to dynamically add a new Service to ServiceBase after it has started?

Tags: c#, windows-services

Taking this basic example:

```
ServiceBase[] servicesToRun;
servicesToRun = new ServiceBase[]
{
 new ServiceFoo(),
 new ServiceFoo()
};
ServiceBase.Run(servicesToRun);

// Some code to add a ServiceFoo into ServiceBase (without having to stop the entire service)
```

Example:

I have a collection of databases which needs to be monitored. My `ServiceBase` spawns a service for each database when it starts up.

How would I add another Service into `ServiceBase` for my database without having to restart the entire service?

Comment: General advice: Use a List<ServiceBase> instead of an array. And if you have more than one thread accessing it make sure to protect it with a lock or a mutex.

Comment: There is no way to add support for a new service to an already running service process.  You'll need to configure the newly created service to use a separate process.